# CDI EntityManager fail

Tags: jpa, cdi

Hibernate says "An exception thrown by Hibernate means you have to rollback your database transaction and close the Session immediately".

When persist method throws a SQLException and the entityManager becomes dirty, if I close the EntityManager, it still in Conversation Scope.

i'm using: tomcat 7, cdi 1.1, hibernate 4.1;

Is there any way to produce a new EntityManager for the current conversation to replace the dirty?

```
@Produces
@ConversationScoped
public EntityManager create(EntityManagerFactory emf) {
    EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();

...
```

ViewBean

```
@Named @ConversationScoped 
public class MyView implements Serializable {
enter code here
@Inject @Getter private EntityManager em;
...
public void persist(){
    try{
        getEm().getTransaction().begin();
        getEm().persist(entityInstance);
        getEm().getTransaction().commit();
    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
        if(getEm().getTransaction().isActive()){
            getEm().getTransaction().rollback();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there is not. Conversation scoped isn't a very good scope for an EntityManager anyway. It should really be Request or Default due to transaction boundaries.